# Using angular redirect with wkwebview

Tags: ios, angularjs, swift, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView which load a angular website.

angular function : `ng-click="redirect('../landing/index.html')"`

`WKWebView` code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   let preferences = WKPreferences()
   preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
   preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
   let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
   configuration.preferences = preferences
   configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
   WebView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)
   WebView.navigationDelegate = self
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
   decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

But the redirection are never call

Answer (score 1):

I have add this delegate to WKWebView, and it's work.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {

    detailWK.load(navigationAction.request)

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Nicolas Perret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48804632/1756736) answer. I'm adding more detail to that:

You have to implement the method from WKUIDelegate.

```
extension MyViewController: WKUIDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
             createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration,
             for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
             windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
        // Open URL in external view controller or same webview
    }
    return nil
}
```

And in your webView instance:

```
webView = WKWebView()
webView.uiDelegate = self
```

I hope this will be more clear.